# How prove this for any real matrices $A_{n\times n}$ are similar to quasi-diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

> show that: 
>   for any real matrices $A_{n\times n}$  are similar to quasi-diagonal  matrices,and the Diagonal block have following form:
>   $\begin{bmatrix}
> \lambda_{0}&1&0&\cdots &0&0\\
> 0&\lambda_{0}&1&\cdots&0&0\\
> \cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\
> 0&0&0&\cdots&\lambda_{0}&1\\
> 0&0&0&\cdots&0&\lambda_{0}
> \end{bmatrix} or
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 0&1&1&0&\cdots&0&0&0&0\\
> -b&-a&0&1&\cdots&0&0&0&0\\
> 0&0&0&1&\cdots&0&0&0&0\\
> \cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\
> \cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\
> 0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&1&1&0\\
> 0&0&0&0&\cdots&-b&-a&0&1\\
> 0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0&0&1\\
> 0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0&-b&-a
> \end{bmatrix}$

where $\lambda_{0},a,b$ be real numbers,and such $a^2<4b$

**This problme is from china linear abgebra problem book,But this book don't have solution for  this problem** ,and I have consider sometimes,at last,I can't solution,Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: It the first matrix supposed to be in [Jordan canonical form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form)?  That is, are the entries directly above the diagonal allowed to be $1$ or $0$?  Also, that second matrix looks a lot like the [real Jordan canonical form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices), certainly, there should be some similarity that goes from one to the other.